# Evaluating $\frac{2^1}{1}+\frac{2^2}{1\cdot3}+\frac{2^3}{1\cdot3\cdot5}+\frac{2^4}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}+\frac{2^5}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I evaluate this infinite series?
$$\frac{2^1}{1}+\frac{2^2}{1\cdot3}+\frac{2^3}{1\cdot3\cdot5}+\frac{2^4}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}+\frac{2^5}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9}+\cdots$$
The approximate value of this series is around $4.05\ldots$

I noticed that each term could be transformed into a product of differences, for instance:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2^3}{1\cdot3\cdot5}&=\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}\right) \\[4pt]
\frac{2^4}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}&=\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{7}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{5}\right) \\[4pt]
&\cdots
\end{align}$$

However upon expanding the terms from the resulting sum of products, the fractions do not seem to cancel out.

Comment: If you put $x = \sqrt{2}$ in the formula given in the following answer and multiply the final result by $2$, you'll have a closed form (well, closed if you count $\mathrm{erf}$ as an elementary function but still): [Sum of $ \frac{1}{1\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}+\frac{1}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}+ \cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3003389) - found using Approach$0$ and copy-pasting your formula.

Comment: Thank you. I was playing around with the expansion of e and replaced $x^n/n!$ with $x^((2n+1)/2)/Γ(n/2)$.       The summation in the question divided by $√π$ was the solution of f(1)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4556193/closed-form-of-a-power-series-involving-double-factorial-sum-n-0-infty) are a few proofs of what is essentially the same formula as the one linked to in Bruno B's comment.

Comment: I honestly can't tell. I just have a high school education in maths. Making sense of these answers will take some time lol. Regardless thank you